# How to speed up page performance in drupal 7

Tags: image, performance, optimization, drupal, drupal-7

[image]I am using drupal 7 and there is content type product images and there is field Search Images with search functionality and it loads 900+ images from database because there is database query behind this which loads images and page display after **20 seconds**.

How I can display this page quickly because I really need to do something to display this page quickly.

How I can optimized this.

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

To increase page speed you can try caching services like:

memcache (https://www.drupal.org/project/memcache)
Redis (https://www.drupal.org/project/redis)

Also you can defer the image load by using Lazy loading. You can load the images as per viewport and when the user scrolls the page the rest of the images will be loaded:

https://www.drupal.org/project/lazy

Comment: Hi I have installed lazy load but as mentioned in screen shot it does not show any check box in field format, can you please help on this

Comment: I have added screen shot above on Format option drop down it does not show any option of lazy loading